# Jquery datatable FixedHeader "Uncaught ReferenceError: FixedHeader is not defined"

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am getting error `Uncaught ReferenceError: FixedHeader is not defined` when I try to use FixedHeade. How I suppose to fix it ? I tried to find out solution but could not get it. My code is as below. Thanks.

```
var dTable = $("table#id_Table").dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": true,
    "aaSorting": [],
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "bSortable": false,
        "aTargets": ["_all"]
    }],
});
new FixedHeader(dTable);
```

Comment: Are you aware what 'Uncaught ReferenceError' means?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you do not have the FixedHeader.js file included in your html document.

https://datatables.net/releases/FixedHeader-2.0.6.zip